# Why are my Mac and Windows machine able to share a flash drive, but they cannot share an external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, windows, usb, external-disk

I am recording Zoom meetings with my Windows machine and storing the videos on an external hard drive. I wanted to consolidate the folders by adding videos I have recorded on my Mac, but I realize I cannot just switch the external hard drive between the two machines.

Why is that possible when using a USB Flash Drive?

Should I then store the videos temporarily on a USB drive on one machine, and then use that to transfer the videos to a permanent external hard drive connected to another machine?

Comment: How is the external drive formatted?

Comment: *Why* can't you switch the drive between the two machines?  What happens?

Comment: @nohillside, I don't know, is there a way to know after the fact?

Comment: @MarcWilson, actually I can switch the drive now. I am using a drive that contains only files. But I am sure that in the past I saw a message on the Mac telling me that the drive was not formatted correctly. Maybe it contained a Windows ISO image? After reading mmmmmm's answer, I tried to transfer a file to the "Windows external hard drive" from the Mac, and I could not do that. So I can access the drive, but only to read files.

Comment: If it's NTFS [which it's very likely to be if you formatted in Windows] then your 'get out of jail *not quite* free card' is [Paragon's NTFS for Mac](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) [approx $£€ 16] which will allow the Mac to write to the drive without further issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not the type of external drive you use e.g. Flash Drive, Hard Disk etc but how the drive is formatted.

Windows and macOS can both read and write FAT and exFAT formatted drives. A flash drive defaults to one of these depending on its size.

By default Windows drives are formatted to NTFS. macOS includes (or perhaps used to include) a driver that allows these to be mounted and read but not written to. You can buy third party programs that allow writing to an NTFS volume from macOS. (There is an open source version but I am not certain that works with later macOS)

macOS will format a drive in APFS or HFS+. Windows can only read those with the help of a third party tool.

So if you want interoperability then you need a third party program or format the drive in exFAT. The downside of the FATlike formats is that the disk cannot hold metadata, for example owner, execution information and is not journaled so that you need to explicitly unmount the drive before removing it otherwise data could be corrupted on the drive.

Comment: Certain metadata such as extended attributes can be held by FATlike formats. This metadata is stored in the hidden `._*` files. This is a macOS specific feature that is ignored by Windows. File flags such as `uchg` are another form a metadata that can be held by FATlike formats. This flag is recognized by Windows to be the readonly attribute.

Comment: Also, I would recommend ejecting any external drive before removal. You answer seems to condone the removal of mounted drives that are journaled.

Comment: @DavidAnderson On a journaled system you won't get data corruption if you remove the drive. If you have not used it for a minute then it can just be pulled out. If you are using it then yes you need to unmount or wait. For a Falsh drive the former is the usual use. I have been around long enough that I remember internal drives corrupting on reboot so I am aware of what can go, wrong - I remember chkdsk

Comment: I disagree with you. I continue to recommend ejecting any external drive before removal.